# How to Install SQL Server Management Studio on external drive

Tags: sql-server

I need a Local DB and the Management Studio on a external drive, because in a few days I have no Internet Connection and I need this Database.

But I will not install it on my Surface...

How do I install any Version of the SQL Management Studio on a external drive? 
Even if I start the install Assistent, it would install it on the C Disk!

Comment: how about using a VM and then use it from VM whenever you need and from wherever you need?

Comment: Good Idea Thx!!